# Erro Include PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, como faço corretamente o include no php codeigniter

segue abaixo o script...quando retiro os scripts em php funciona corretamente.

```
<?php include('includes/header.inc.php'); ?>

<body>
<div id="header" class="container">
    <?php include('includes/navigation.inc.php'); ?>
</div>
<div id="banner-wrapper2">
    <div id="banner" class="container">
        <div class="boxD">
            <h3>Quem somos</h3>

        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

Já com o include, dá o erro abaixo:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: include(includes/header.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: pages/quemsomos.php

Line Number: 1

Backtrace:

File: /home/site.com.br/application/views/frontend/pages/quemsomos.php
Line: 1
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/site.com.br/application/views/frontend/pages/quemsomos.php
Line: 1
Function: include

File: /home/buscadefornecedores.com.br/application/libraries/Template.php
Line: 29
Function: view

File: /home/site.com.br/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 23
Function: load

File: /home/site.com.br/public/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

este é o arquivo routes.php
está na web  no diretorio: /application/config/routes.php

$route['/includes/'] = 'includes/header.inc';
$route['/includes/'] = 'includes/navigation.inc';
$route['/includes/'] = 'includes/footer.inc';

os includes na pasta:  /application/includes/

na pasta public tenho somente a pasta assets e o index.php

Se alguém puder me ajudar com essa dúvida...

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Por razão de segurança e do próprio escopo do que o framework do Codeigniter enxerga, você não pode se servir de outros arquivos externos ao projeto para incluir em suas views. Em outras palavras, você está tentando incluir  `/home/buscadefornecedores.com.br/application/libraries/Template.php` em `/home/site.com.br/application/views/frontend/pages/quemsomos.php`. Estes são projetos diferentes. Tal referência não é possível.

Mas você poderia referenciar códigos de trechos de uma view em outra, desde que do mesmo projeto, da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
// Nesse caso, dirname(__FILE__) retorna o diretório das suas ../application/views
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Para esse exemplo, você precisaria ter um diretório `/includes` com seus trechos de código logo abaixo de `/application/views`. Não é necessário configurar routes para tal.

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria você utilizar o conceito de partial view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <?php $this->load->view('meta'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

            <div id="content">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aonde você faz o load de outras views dentro de uma só.